# How to active scroll with a bokeh gridplot?

Tags: python, bokeh

I haven't found how to activate the wheel_zoom by default when using gridplot to organize different plots.

`active_scroll='wheel_zoom'`

```
p1 = figure(title='figure #1')
p1.line([1,2,3,4,5], [2,5,8,2,7], color="red")

p2 = figure(title='figure #2', x_range=p1.x_range)
p2.line([1,2,3,4,5], [4,3,4,1,3], color="blue")

p3 = figure(title='figure #3', x_range=p1.x_range)
p3.line([1,2,3,4,5], [5,1,6,3,2], color="green")

show(gridplot([p1,p2, p3], ncols=1, plot_width=600, plot_height=200))
```

Answer (score 3):

I followed the instructions on [bokeh dokumentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#setting-the-active-tools) in the section "setting tools to active" and I found the parameter `active_scroll`. You can set it to `"wheel_zoom"`, then this tool will be activated.

To activate it for every whole figure, you have to add it 3 times (to every subfigure) or you have to merge all 3 tools of the subfigure into one in the gridplot using `merge_tools=True`. Otherwise the figure corresponds only to a part.

This code snippet is working in my jupyter notebook, **but** the wheel zoom tool is not marked as active as you would expect. In fact the first click on the symbol will activate it again.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
output_notebook()

p1 = figure(title='figure #1', active_scroll ="wheel_zoom")
p1.line([1,2,3,4,5], [2,5,8,2,7], color="red")

p2 = figure(title='figure #2', x_range=p1.x_range)
p2.line([1,2,3,4,5], [4,3,4,1,3], color="blue")

p3 = figure(title='figure #3', x_range=p1.x_range)
p3.line([1,2,3,4,5], [5,1,6,3,2], color="green")

show(gridplot([p1,p2, p3], ncols=1, plot_width=600, plot_height=200, merge_tools=True))
```

Comment: Indeed the active_scroll seems to be activated despite it not indicated as pushed (blue line undersore). But the behaviour is not the same, the scroll causes the whole cell of the notebook to scroll not the separated figures. If I click on the wheel zoom then the expected behaviour is there (no scroll on the entire cell but on each figures).

Comment: I can not see the behaviour your are describing in my notebook. For me it looks like both activaions (with and without underline) are working the same. But maybe this depends on the environment (and maybe bokeh and python version, too).

Comment: Well, I opend an issue on GitHub because of this, because it works fine for plots without any layout like gridplot. Maybe this can be solved in futur versions.

Comment: Yes, it could be worth. 
I confirme that this behaviour apperas with bokeh 2.2.3, notebook 6.1.1, python 3.7.9
Anyway the fact  to have not a pushed 'wheel zoom' button may indicate that the setting is uncomplete or incorrect. Let me know the issue you will post. Thanks