# Bokeh toolbar indicators wrong when merging tools in gridplot

Tags: python, plot, bokeh, toolbar

### Problem statement

When grouping bokeh plots into a [gridplot](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/layouts.html#gridplot) tool indicators appear to have the wrong state. This is the case for at least [WheelZoomTool](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html#bokeh.models.WheelZoomTool) and [HoverTool](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html#bokeh.models.HoverTool), though could be the case for some other tools as well. The problem is purely visual. The state of the underlying tools is correct as set in the code. Clicking on the tools a few times seems to bring the indicators back into sync with the actual tool state.

Here is a steps to reproduce the behaviour (in Jupyter for simplicity):

```
'''  Minimal example of the problem
'''
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
output_notebook()
x = list(range(11))
y0 = x
y1 = [10 - i for i in x]
y2 = [abs(i - 5) for i in x]

# create three plots
s1 = figure(
    background_fill_color="#fafafa",
    active_scroll="wheel_zoom",
    active_inspect=None,
    width=300,
    height=300,
)
s1.circle(x, y0, size=12, alpha=0.8, color="#53777a")
s1.add_tools(HoverTool())

s2 = figure(
    background_fill_color="#fafafa",
    active_scroll="wheel_zoom",
    active_inspect=None,
    width=300,
    height=300,
)
s2.triangle(x, y1, size=12, alpha=0.8, color="#c02942")
s2.add_tools(HoverTool())

s3 = figure(
    background_fill_color="#fafafa",
    active_scroll="wheel_zoom",
    active_inspect=None,
    width=300,
    height=300,
)
s3.square(x, y2, size=12, alpha=0.8, color="#d95b43")
s3.add_tools(HoverTool())

# make a grid
grid = gridplot([[s2, s3]], width=300, height=300, merge_tools=True, toolbar_location='right')

show(s1)
show(grid)
```

The example above produces the following result:

[image]

### Questions

I have two questions about this

1. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?
2. If this is a bug, does anyone have an elegant workaround? I do have one of my own but it is **very** far from elegant.

### What I have tried

At the moment I wrap gridplot into a wrapper function which first creates an instance of [GridPlot](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/plots.html#bokeh.models.GridPlot) then decorates it by looping through the tools in the toolbar and manually setting the indicators.

Here is a snapshot of code:

```
def customized_gridplot(children:list, **kwargs)->GridPlot:
    """ Calls ``bokeh.layouts.gridplot`` and decorates returned gridplot.
        Merges the tools on the toolbar
        Fiddles with active indicators of the tools to correct them
    
    Args:
        children (list): List of items that will be passed to ``bokeh.layouts.gridplot``
        **kwargs: Other kwargs that will be passed to ``bokeh.layouts.gridplot``
    
    Returns:
        GridPlot: Decorated instance of GridPlot
    """

    kwargs_default = dict(
        toolbar_options = dict(logo=None),  # No Bokeh logo
        merge_tools = True,                 # Group identical tools from different plots
    )
    kwargs_default.update(kwargs)

    gp = gridplot(
        children=children,
        **kwargs_default
    )

    # This next part fiddles with toolbar tool indicators.
    # Below we manipulate the state of these indicators !only!.
    # This will not impact the state of the tools themselves.
    for tool in gp.toolbar.tools:
        if tool.__class__.__name__ == 'ToolProxy':
            if tool.tools[0].__class__.__name__ == 'PanTool':
                tool.active = True
            if tool.tools[0].__class__.__name__ == 'BoxZoomTool':
                tool.active = False
            if tool.tools[0].__class__.__name__ == 'WheelZoomTool':
                tool.active = True
            if tool.tools[0].__class__.__name__ == 'HoverTool':
                tool.active = True
  return gp
```

As you can see the workaround I use is really poor and does not generalize well, the indicator states are litterally hardcoded which is not suitable for my use case.

Any advise is appreciated

*All the code provided above is not my actual porduction code but rather a compiled examples to demonstrate the problem.*

### Also relevant

[How to active scroll with a bokeh gridplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64774658/how-to-active-scroll-with-a-bokeh-gridplot#comment114574460_64774754)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49297520/1540660

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/10107

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround for your example you can set and unset the tools to active and inactive. For this you have to know the position for each tool.

```
grid.toolbar.tools[1].active = True
grid.toolbar.tools[-1].active = True
grid.toolbar.tools[-1].active = False

show(grid)
```

It looks a bit odd, but the hovertool is inactive and has to be active first, before it can be deactivated. This is why the on tool is toggled twice.